# Coalesce returning wrong value after a function call followed by multiplication

Tags: sql, linqpad, coalesce

I have a report that presents information and I'm getting inconsistent information based on what appears to be some issue with a SQL view or possibly a SQL Function  nested within the view. I've tried finding a way to debug the SQL View, however, it looks like SSMS only will debug Stored Procedures, so I'm not really sure how to step through and see what is happening. It really has me stumped and I can't help but wonder if it isn't a rounding issue.
GetItemAverageCost `RETURNS DECIMAL(12,2)` and the DataType in sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM is System.Int64 / bigint (sidenote: I'm confused about why LINQPad shows 2 data types for that column. In the tree on the left, after expanding the sitli table and hovering over the QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM the balloon BigInt NOT NULL pops up, but when I Take(100) and hover over the column in the result set it says System.Int64). Anyroad, here is the COALESCE function.

`COALESCE((dbo.GetItemAverageCost(ItemModel.IDItemModel)*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM) / ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemModel.UOMFactor, 0),1),0) -- 259.73`


`--ROUND(COALESCE((dbo.GetItemAverageCost(ItemModel.IDItemModel)*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM) / ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemModel.UOMFactor, 0),1),0),2) -- 259.73`


`--COALESCE(ROUND((dbo.GetItemAverageCost(ItemModel.IDItemModel)*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM) / ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemModel.UOMFactor,2), 0),1),0) -- 259.70`


`--COALESCE((ROUND(dbo.GetItemAverageCost(ItemModel.IDItemModel),2)*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM) / ISNULL(NULLIF(ItemModel.UOMFactor, 0),1),0) -- 259.73`

original / wrong coalesce:

`COALESCE(dbo.GetItemAverageCost(ItemModel.IDItemModel)*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM,0)`

I'm not sure what else to include, but I haven't found many resources online that offer insight into this kind of a situation. Many thanks in advance for your time.

EDIT: GetItemAverageCost:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION GetItemAverageCost
        (
            @IDItemModel varchar(8000)
        )

        RETURNS DECIMAL(16,4)
        --RETURNS DECIMAL(12,2)
        AS
        BEGIN
        RETURN
        (
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(AVG(poli.UnitPrice),0) as AvgCost
--          COALESCE(ROUND(AVG(poli.UnitPrice),0),2) as AvgCost 260.00
        FROM ItemModel im
        LEFT JOIN VendorItem vi
            ON im.IDItemModel = vi.IDItemModel
        JOIN POLineItem poli
            ON vi.IDVendorItem = poli.IDVendorItem

        WHERE
            im.IDItemModel = @IDItemModel

        GROUP BY
            im.IDItemModel,
            im.ItemNumber
        )
        END
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what is wrong?

Comment: @NetMage Thank you for your response. When a given report is run, there are no errors thrown. But the calculations are off. For example a part number 12 shows a quantity of 24 were issued at a cost of $259.73. However, each part costs $10.82 so the calculation should be $259.68. I'm not sure where the difference of 5 cents is coming from. The $259.73 is the result of the COALESCE function above. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Also, there are other parts that are displayed with no errors in the calculation. The parts of which only 1 were issued don't appear to have any errors at all. The problem seems to generally occur when more than one part was issued. However, some of the parts that had more than 1 issued (e.g. 2, 4, 12, etc.) had a correct cost calculated.

Comment: Where does the $10.82 come from? What does `GetItemAverageCost` return for part # 12?

Comment: @NetMage The $10.82 is a result of the GetItemAverageCost. GetItemAverageCost returns $10.82 - in theory.

Comment: Are you sure? I am thinking it returns 10.8221?

Comment: @NetMage you may be right. How could I verify that? I don't see any way to step through the execution of the GetItemAverageCost function to check what it's returning. Also, wouldn't it have to be $10.82 since the GetItemAverageCost truncates the last 2 digits with RETURNS DECIMAL(12,2)?

Comment: What is the type of `QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM`? The rules for SQL Server say multiplying two `Decimal(12,2)` will result in a answer type of `Decimal(25,4)`.

Comment: @NetMage the type for QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM (according to what I see in SQL Server Management Studio) is bigint. Currently I'm researching the rules for SQL Server which say what happens when multiplying Decimal by bigint.

Comment: There are two relevant issues: 1 [Data Type Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), 2 [Precision, Scale and Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - combined they say `bigint` becomes `Decimal(12,2)` and multiple result will be `Decimal(17,4)`. Can you show the code for `GetItemAverageCost`?

Comment: @NetMage yes, I'll add GetItemAverageCost to my original post.

Comment: What is the data type for `poli.UnitPrice` (Including precision/scale)

Comment: `AVG(poli.UnitPrice)` is yielding a decimal with more than 2 significant digits is why; but then you're truncating those extra digits by returning a decimal (12,2)  So the "Average" unit cost isn't 10.82 it's 10.8220833333333

Comment: @xQbert yes, but isn't 10.82 being returned by GetItemAverageCost? Also, poli.UnitPrice is `money` datatype.

Comment: Yes 10.82 is being returned  by the function; but only because it's getting truncated by the data type's precision defined by the return val of the function.  If you run the query inside the function supplying the 12 part number you'll see that the value returned is actually 10.822083333333 but the `returns decimal (12,2)` is truncating it to 10.82.

Comment: How was the math done to determine the 259.73?  Did it round or not round and WHEN did it round?  your function is rounding before the multiplication on unit price which is why you expect it to be 259.68.  Perhaps the method used to determine the 259.73 didn't round until after the total was calculated... 10.82208333333*24 = 259.7299999 becomes 259.73  This is often the case in gasoline where the price is fractions of cents 2.59 9/10 but the rounding isn't done until you actually show the total amount.  I had problems with prices having fractions of cents early on but it's how business works.

Comment: @xQbert it appears to have a scale of 4 (places after the decimal) though I don't know what the precision is.

Comment: So between the average returning more than 2 decimals and having 4 decimals in a unit price, any type of rounding before multiplying the quantity will cause the problem.  which you're doing (not really rounding but truncating to 2 decimals)  So in your example 259.73 is calculated not using your function; where as using your function you get the 259.68.  The difference is when rounding is applied.  yours does it before multiplying by quantity, the 259.73 was done after multiplying by quantity.

Comment: @xQbert I will research further how the math was done to determine the 259.73. You've posed some good questions / possibilities. I probably won't be able to respond until tomorrow afternoon, but I appreciate your insight and look forward to unraveling this mystery. Many thanks, Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so many thanks to all who helped along the way. There were a couple of issues preventing me from getting the correct answer. For one thing, I was working with the incorrect expression for much of the time. Secondly, after I figured out which expression to use, it was a matter of placing the ROUND function in the correct place.

So, the expression I should have been using to get my average cost is:

```
COALESCE(dbo.GetItemAverageCost(Item.IDItemModel) / ISNULL(NULLIF(UOMFactor, 0),1),0)
```

When I moved this into the WorkOrderItemInstructionPartCosts View, my report was then producing $10.82. Then I added `*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM` to the line and was getting $259.73. Then I applied the ROUND function to the COALESCE function and voila! the correct value ($259.68) is being produced.

The final line looks like this:

```
ROUND(COALESCE(dbo.GetItemAverageCost(ItemModel.IDItemModel) / ISNULL(NULLIF(UOMFactor, 0),1),0),2)*sitli.QuantityIssuedAtStockUOM
```

Once again, thank you to all who helped me in the effort to resolve this and sorry for not having accurate information to begin with.
Best,
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

To fix; have your function return 16,4 instead of 12,2 and then ROUND two two decimals after multiplying by the quantity.

"When a given report is run, there are no errors thrown. But the calculations are off. For example a part number 12 shows a quantity of 24 were issued at a cost of $259.73. However, each part costs $10.82 so the calculation should be $259.68. I'm not sure where the difference of 5 cents is coming from. The $259.73 is the result of the COALESCE function above. Hopefully this makes sense"

Run the SQL only for part 12 independent of the function and you'll see the average is 10.822083333333333333333333333333 (10.82 5/24ths)

- 24*unitprice = $259.73
- unitprice = 259.73/24
- unit price = $10.82 5/24.

You'll see the variance is $.05

- 10.82 5/24ths. *24 = 259.73
- 10.82 * 24 = 259.68

That difference of 5cents doesn't go evenly into the remaining 24. thus the rounding error when using your function.

When you think of going to the store and buying something it's always at amounts to the whole penny.  When you go to the gas station they charge to the nearest .00001 cents.  (or in your case 4 decimals)

The rounding when using fractions of pennies isn't done until multiplied by the quantity or when actual cash needs to change hands.   If done too early you get rounding errors you are seeing.

Thus you eliminate over/under charging rounding errors and at most you'll charge a fraction of a penny less or more than you should.

Comment: I took your advice and changed the return to `DECIMAL(16,4)` and have been playing with the ROUND function and still seem to be getting the wrong return. I will continue to do so until I get it right.

Comment: So I've been experimenting with placing the ROUND function in a variety of places in the view, however, they continue to fail to produce the right number. I also realized that I've been using the wrong COALESCE function in the View. I've edited the original post to show the COALESCE that is actually producing the amounts. Sorry for confusion.